# Clicking highlighted Link in Unoredered list

Tags: html, css

Here's a sample of the page I'm working with. The problem is that the user has to click on the link before they are directed to the target page. Is there a way of making the highlighted box for each of those links active and respond to click as well?

My users are complaining that unless they click on the link, clicking in the box does not work.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
 <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <style type="text/css">
    li {
        background-color: #F5F2EE;
        background-position: left top;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        border: 1px solid #E9E3DD;
        height: auto;
        width: 100px;
        margin-bottom: 4px;
        padding: 4px 5px 4px 20px;
    }

    li a, span {
        color: #4B0F19;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    li:hover {
        background-color: #DEB887;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    </style>

    <body>
        Hello world

        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://google.com">Please see this</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://msn.com">Another link</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://twitter.com">The main link</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://bbc.co.uk">fourth link</a></li>
        </ul>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Off topic, but your `style` belongs inside your `head`.

Comment: @Mob Not if you click a bit away from the text and close to the edges, where it is no longer an `a` but is still a `li`.

Comment: @ANeves Ok, I got it.  Julie see also http://css-tricks.com/examples/ButtonMaker/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `li` have 0 padding and margin, the `a` `display: block;`, and move the styles to `a`.
This way the `a` will expand to fill all the `li`, and so there will be no area that is part of the menu item but it not filled by the `a`.

Does this make sense? Do you understand the different approach?

live example: http://jsfiddle.net/NB6Wx/

---

(You could also capture the click on the `li` with JavaScript, and trigger a click in the `a`... but that would be patching a problem that can actually be solved.)
(A bad solution.)

Comment: Thanks alot for that, it's now working well. I massively appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Well as far as i understood the problem is `<a>` is displaying as inline element. you can modify the CSS to make it block element and it will take the whole `<li>` element.

Like

```
    li a {
       display:block;
       width:100%;
    }
```

Comment: Better, but still flawed because the li has padding: try the first 20px on the left.

Answer (score 0):

You Need to add `li a {display:block;}` to your CSS.

Here is a Working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/refhat/8CqNn/9/)

Comment: Better, but still flawed because the `li` has padding: try the first 20px on the left.

Comment: Thanks for feedback, I just copied her code, and gave a hurried solution.